# Python GTTS / Failed to connect. Probable cause: Unknown

Tags: python

```
from playsound import playsound
from gtts import gTTS,gTTSError

 def playaudio(audio):
    playsound(audio)

def convert_to_audio(text):
    audio =gTTS(text)
    >- audio.save("textaud.mp3") -<
    playaudio("textaud.mp3")

convert_to_audio("my name is joe")
```

I'm using Anaconda Environments.
I'm getting a error in highlighted line.

That error is:`Failed to connect. Probable cause: Unknown`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZMVI.png

The solutions I tried:

1. Updated Windows
2. Uninstalled and Reinstalled gTTS

Comment: Which gtts version are you using ? There was an issue with version before 2.1.2 that may be related to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

So I have used gtts in a recent project and one thing I noticed is that I get this error every time I run my code without an internet connection. As soon as my device is connected, it works fine for me. Even the code you provided worked as it should (after correcting the indentation and deleting ">-" from your save audio command), so be sure to be connected to the internet. Hope this'll help!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this.

```
from playsound
from gtts import gTTS

def playaudio(audio):
    playsound(audio)

def convert_to_audio(text):
    audio =gTTS(text=text, lang='en', tld='com')
    audio.save("textaud.mp3")
    playaudio("textaud.mp3")

convert_to_audio("my name is joe")
```